# Possible to integrate Google AppEngine and Google Code for continuous integration?

Tags: python, svn, google-app-engine, continuous-integration, google-code

Anyone have any thoughts on how/if it is possible to integrate Google Code commits to cause a Google AppEngine deployment of the most recent code?

I have a simple Google AppEngine project's source hosted on Google Code and would love if everytime I committed to Subversion, that AppEngine would reflect the latest commit.  I don't mind if things are broken on the live site since the project is for personal use mainly and for learning.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to tie into the subversion commit for the Code repository and/or how to kickoff the deployment to AppEngine? Ideally the solution would not require anything manual from me nor any type of server/listener software on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Code Project Hosting now supports [Post-Commit Web Hooks](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/PostCommitWebHooks), which ping a project-owner-specified URL after every commit. This would eliminate the need to regularly poll your Google Code repository.

Answer (score 5):

[Made By Sofa](http://www.madebysofa.com) had a [blog post](http://www.madebysofa.com/#blog/appengine_hosting) about their workflow with Google App Engine. In the second last paragraph they have [attached a subversion hook](http://www.madebysofa.com/media/downloads/appengine_deploy.sh) that when when someone commits code it will automatically deploy to Google App Engine. It would take a little bit of tweaking (because it works on the server side not the client) but you could do the same.

Comment: It'd certainly be doable to write a client-side post-commit hook for this.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to have some glue on another computer which monitored SVN commits and deployed a new version for you. Google Code has yet to develop and release an API (which they need to do soon if they're serious about this whole development thing), but GAE can be deployed to with relative automated ease, so I wouldn't have thought it should be that difficult. The deployment process, however, will vary with each project, so that's something you need to sort out yourself (you might wanna take a look at the [fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/) deployment system). Then, just set a cron job going which updates a local SVN checkout on the middle machine, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting, but not yet possible, AFAIK.  I have been looking for that option in Google Code with no success.

The only solution I can figure out is to install something in your machine that checks for changes in your SVN repository.

I'll be happy to hear about other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who are using Github, this feature from the GAE team would make us all seriously consider switching to Google Code...

Comment: It'd be easy (for some definition of 'easy') to write a github post-commit hook for this.